# Did a submarine ever torpedo and sink a destroyer?

Tags: naval, battle, submarine

The naval [battle](http://dubm.de/en/the-bitter-fight/) of [U-405](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_submarine_U-405) versus [USS Borie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Borie_(DD-215)) sank the Borie, but that was due to its own action of ramming U-405, which had a stronger hull to withstand depth pressures.

Did a submarine ever sink a destroyer with a torpedo?  Or with a deck gun?

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_US_Navy_ships_sunk_or_damaged_in_action_during_World_War_II might be a good starting point

Comment: On 1/24/43 the USS Wahoo, under capt. Morton,  torpedoed IJN Harasume with a down the throat shot in a harbor forcing the destroyer to beach itself to avoid sinking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why yes, indeed.

I count, fast and dirty, at least 37 Japanese destroyers sunk by US submarines in WW2.  A good place to look is the [Joint Army Navy Assessment Committee](https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/Japan/IJN/JANAC-Losses/) though it requires a little perseverance.  At least 9 US destroyers or destroyer escorts were sunk by German submarines and at least 8 sunk by Japanese submarines (including midgets and Kaitens).  These can be found in the easiest format here. [Wiki - US Navy Losses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_Navy_losses_in_World_War_II).

Pretty sure the Royal Navy and the Royal Netherlands Navy submarines and other Allied navies had their share of enemy destroyers as well.  And the same lost their share of destroyers to Germans, Italian or Japanese submarines, for example perhaps here: [Wiki - Royal Navy Losses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Royal_Navy_losses_in_World_War_II).